# Webview lost logged user session when user keep app open or in background

Tags: android, android-webview, session-state

Hi all i am developeing an app where i load a website built in magento which has session of 1 hour for logged user. what i am doing to logged  in website with the help of webview then all thing working fine , problem created when uswr leave app open or put in ackground and when comes to the app and try to open another url then it keep asking for login again , but i dont want to login aging by user is ther any way to login in background when time exceeded. So user can navigate anywhere whitout login.

Answer (score 1):

add a cookiemanager to your activity:

```
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
```

Comment: I did the same but the problem is magento have only 1 hour session so it needs to login again.